# Can self be overwritten by a queue object within class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, self

I have a python pexpect script that logs in to servers frequently, and each time it tries to log in, I get a DUO push, which is very unreliable (not sure if it's the app on Android or the DUO system itself, but that is not relevant to my question). I'm trying to avoid DUO pushes by re-using sessions in the queue.

I have a class called Session to open/close sessions. I also have a global Queue defined. Whenever I'm done using a session, instead of closing the pexpect handle, I do q.put(self). self contains the active pexpect session. Next time I need to login, I first check to see if there is an item in the Queue. If there is, I would like to do self = q.get(), hence overwriting my "self" with the object in the Queue. Here is example code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
from globals import q

class Session:
   def __init__(self, ip):
       self.user = flask_login.current_user.saneid
       self.pass = flask_login.current_user.sanepw
       self.ip = ip
       self.handle = None

   def __enter__(self):
       if not q.empty():
          self = q.get()
       else:
          # login to node
          self.handle = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@node')
          ...
       return(self.handle)

   def __exit__(self, *args):
       q.put(self)
```

Is this good practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: `self` is a local variable inside the method. You can reassign it if you want; it will not affect anything outside that method. It might make your method a little confusing for a reader; you can avoid it by using a variable other than `self`.

Comment: …and besides that, it would not be a good practice even if it worked.

Comment: Got it khelwood. Not clear on martineau's comment though. Not good practice to keep the same name when retrieving from queue (ie self vs some other variable name), or not good practice to use a queue to store the object?

Comment: Why not manage the queue outside of the Session Class.  You can then push the Session instance onto the queue on exit.  You can then create one or more Session Instances and populate the queue with their instance pointers and only create a new session class when the queue is empty.  Within each Session, the self value refers to the instance of Session, so jnow each queue entry points to different instances.

Comment: Right. I just thought keeping everything in the same place (ie creating/saving/releasing sessions) would be neater. Point taken.